# Is there an O(1) solution to find the kth-smallest element in an implicit min-heap?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, arrays, heaps

I know this would be an *O(k log n)* operation on a traditional heap, and I know there are ways to maintain Kth-smallest over a stream of inserts/deletes for constant-time access...

My question though is, when we have an implicit array representation of a min-heap, e.g.:

```
min_heap = [1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 54, 12, 12, 34]
```

In this case, is it possible to infer the Kth-smallest value's index from the value of K, so you can use the array index to get the value in O(1) time?

Comment: No, not in general. For instance, finding the $n$th smallest element (the largest element) will take at least $\Omega(n)$ in the worst case. Similar argument to what's given [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/80362/68251).

Comment: Another reason for No. If this is the case then we could extract a sorted list in linear time $O(1)$ for each $k$th smallest element. We can also [create a min heap in linear time](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/77999/68251) thus we could sort in linear time!

Comment: Great point, I never looked at it that way. If this were possible, it would enable things that are clearly impossible, therefore it must not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. If this is the case then we could extract a sorted list in linear time; $O(1)$ for each $k$th smallest element. We can also [create a min heap in linear time](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/77999/68251) thus we could sort in linear time! We know comparison sorting has an $\Omega(n \log n)$ lower bound worst case, so this is not possible.